# Check for Null in a gridview

Tags: asp.net

I am storing a image datatype in my DB.
But while checking it

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="lbEvidence" runat="server"
                        Text='<%# CheckNull (Eval("Evidence")) %>'
```

aspx.cs

```
protected string CheckNull(object objGrid)
        {   // checks whether there is evidence file or not

            if (object.ReferenceEquals(objGrid, DBNull.Value))
            {
                return "";

            }
            else
            {
                return "Record Found";             
            }
        }
```

Even when the image in the DB is NULL, here objgrid takes a value System.Byte[4] and returns Record Found. 
Works fine when the image is not null

Any hints
Sun

Comment: Set a break point here: if (object.ReferenceEquals(objGrid, DBNull.Value)) and in the immediate window, look at the value of objGrid

Comment: @TheGeekYouNeed: objGrid = System.Bytes[4] for a NULL in the table. else it is System.Bytes[....]

Answer (score 0):

what happens when you do this?

```
protected string CheckNull(object objGrid)
        {   // checks whether there is evidence file or not

          return (object == null) ? string.empty : "Record Found";  
        }
```

Comment: no change. objGrid is taking System.Byte[4] if the image in the DB is NULL

Comment: what does objGrid equal when it is an image?  Is the null in the database being set to another value in your data layer?

Comment: :objGrid takes System.Byte[] Text='<%#CheckNull(Eval("Evidence")) %>'. Evidence in the table is a Image Datatype.